# append() function is taking a long time to run

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, I just got started in Python and therefore I do not have much knowledge. I tried to search this problem over and I could not find a proper solution.

Just to make a brief: I am studying a traffic accidents database that has almost 165000 rows and 39 columns. One of the steps that I am taking is running apriori algorithm (from apyori lab) in this base.
If you want, you can [donwnload the base (.csv) here](https://www1.prf.gov.br/arquivos/index.php/s/0rgaxoZ2Fu7VWvM).

However, in order to do that, I have to transform my pandas database into a list and this is the part that I am having problems.

I am using the following code:

```
def list_apriori(df):
apr = []
for i in range (0, 164699):
    apr.append([str(df.values[i,j]) for j in range (0,38)])

return apr
```

I left this code running for almost 40 minutes and it didn't finish, so I thought that maybe there is an improved way to do so.
I've made a test with:

```
def list_apriori(df):
apr = []
for i in range (0, 50):
    apr.append([str(df.values[i,j]) for j in range (0,10)])

return apr
```

It finished in less than 5 minutes (which I believe that is a long time given that it is only running in 51 rows and 11 columns).
I also tried to change the computer, but I did not feel any difference.

Do you have any suggestions of if and how I can improve the code in order to run it faster?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT
I believe that the problem was the conversion to string. Thanks @ninesalt for the help!
The code that worked is the following:

```
def list_apriori(df):
result = df.astype(str)
apr = []
for i in range (0, 164699):
    apr.append([df.values[i,j] for j in range (0,38)])

return apr
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The operating in your for loop (first code fragment) runs more than 6 millions time because you're doing it 39 times per iteration

Comment: Thanks, i should have read it fully. I will try to do that. 
Sorry.

Comment: @MatheusTurchet I am doubt about `df.values[i,j]`. You have to time the `df.values[i,j]` section. Because the python `append` should not take this much time.

Comment: @RamIdavalapati I watched a video that the same code ran in ~4k rows and 20 columns and it took less than 5 seconds. I do agree with you that it should not take this amount of time, but I am not finding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is exactly what you wanted but without the loops. This takes 3 seconds on my PC and the dataframe is the same size as the one in your example `(165000, 39)`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (165000, 39))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
result = df.astype(str)

firstrow = result.iloc[[0]]
print(firstrow)  # prints first row as a string
```

Whenever you have something that you think is an expensive operation, there's almost always an easier and more efficient way to do it with the library you're using, you just have to check the docs.

Comment: from what I understood, this just converts all my df in string values (sorry if I am not right). What I want to do is convert them into string and then create a list (which I named apr) with these values.

Comment: @matheusturchet Thats the same thing, the df is a list of lists. What you want to do is go row by row and add the the current 1D list to apr to make it 2D. My answer does the same thing.

Comment: it worked perfectly. thanks! i just do not understand why the code that i wrote was not effective.